# Is there a way to use Chrome's local overrides / workspace with Angular 2+'s ts file?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

The question is: Is there a way to use Chrome's local overrides / workspace with Angular 2+'s ts file?

Example: I want to edit in Chrome .ts files while my Angular 2+ (v5 in my case) application is running ( `angular-cli`)?

I have found a way to do that for [`scss` files](https://medium.com/@lampt2509/set-up-persistence-scss-from-chrome-devtools-for-angular-220ce0818568) but not for `ts`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that with **angular-cli with source maps + chrome dev tools latest (tested on Chrome v65 on MacOS)** opening a file in *source* tab ( `ctrl/cmd+P`), allows to edit it and the edited files are reflected directly in the filesystem.

Notes:

- Add your project folders in "workspaces" in chrome dev tools
- There are usually 2 files for each component (the es5 and es6 one). Edit the es6 one! (usually under `webpack://...`- not *internal* - namespace)

Comment: does it work with html too? I often need to add classes and ids when I do unit testing or e2e testing

Comment: with plain HTML, probably. I didn't test it since I was using it for an Angular which generated custom html then handled by the framework via JS, not the browser